# Twitter like Animation for an Android ImageView?

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview, android-animation

Twitter on iOS has this nice bird animation on start.

[image] ([Source](https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/SKSplashView))

**How can I make such an animation with an Android ImageView?**

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Animation/tree/master/src/com/example/animation)

Comment: Scale + Alpha animation

Comment: When do I have to call this in ``onStart()``? Could you add a code example?

Comment: Refer to this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal Check this

Comment: @confile chek my ans and related link though ans has been accepted but there is a library for android also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as:

```
findViewById(R.id.image_view).animate()
    .setStartDelay(500)
    .setDuration(1000)
    .scaleX(20)
    .scaleY(20)
    .alpha(0);
```

---

Make sure the image view is centered in your layout:

```
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

---

To modify the animation further you can:

- Delay the animation
- Use an decelerating (or other) interpolator
- Modify the scale factors

Comment: Is is possible to change the animations?

Comment: the first bounce animation is not coming in my code what to do for that?

Answer (score 2):

It's called Splash Screen and here is a tutorial how to achieve it - [link](http://androidsrc.net/implement-android-splash-screen/)

The difference is that you need to add after line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

Following code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_animation); 
image.startAnimation(animation);
```

And add in your `res/anim` new file `my_animation.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

   <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
          android:toXScale="5.0" android:toYScale="5.0" 
          android:duration="3000" android:fillBefore="false"
          android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" />

   <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
          android:duration="3000"/>

</set>
```

Comment: No this is not the correct one. It should scale from the center.

Answer (score 0):

**Agree with above answer but there is another  solution: -**

[THis link](https://github.com/ykabaran/TwitterSplash) may be useful for you just **download** the code and as per the link suggests

**You can create in code:**

```
// create and customize the view
SplashView splashView = new SplashView(context);
// the animation will last 0.5 seconds
splashView.setDuration(500);
// transparent hole will look white before the animation
splashView.setHoleFillColor(Color.WHITE);
// this is the Twitter blue color
splashView.setIconColor(Color.rgb(23, 169, 229));
// a Twitter icon with transparent hole in it
splashView.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_twitter);
// remove the SplashView from MainView once animation is completed
splashView.setRemoveFromParentOnEnd(true);
```

**or in XML:**

```
<com.yildizkabaran.twittersplash.view.SplashView 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yildizkabaran.twittersplash"
    android:id="@+id/splash_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter"
    app:iconColor="@color/twitter_blue"
    app:duration="500"
    app:holeFillColor="@color/white"
    app:removeFromParentOnEnd="true" />
```

then to run the animation, simply call:

--> run the animation and listen to the animation events (listener can be left as null)

```
splashView.splashAndDisappear(new ISplashListener(){
    @Override
    public void onStart(){

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(float completionFraction){

}

@Override
public void onEnd(){

}
```

});`

**Output will be**

[image]

-Hope you find your answer.

Comment: @confile check this library also